# How can I force my ChartJS canvas legend to stay in a single column?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, chart.js

I've checked some different sources and looked around the options, but I can't seem to be able to get my legend to stay in one column. For example,

[image: JS Chart]

In the picture above, you'll notice one piece of the legend is getting cut off and placed to the side.  This happens at around <= 550 pixels.  I would like to force them all to remain in one column.  Here is a JSFiddle with the chart recreated.  I had to paste in some imports in the beginning of the JS file, because I couldn't find them in the fiddle options.  Scroll to the bottom for the relevant stuff.  Any help would be appreciated. https://jsfiddle.net/lochrine/02yrpcxg/

Here is the relevant JS:

```
//Line Graph Script

$('.line-graph').each(function () {
    var legendlabels = $(this).data('legendlabels');
    var datapoints = $(this).data('datapoints');
    var suppliers = $(this).data('suppliers');

    var datatype = $(this).data('datatype');
    var yAxisString = "Amounts";
    if (datatype == "units") { yAxisString = "Units Sold"; }
    else if (datatype == "money") { yAxisString = "Amount (Dollars)"; }

    console.log(datatype);

    new Chart($(this).get(0).getContext('2d'), {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: legendlabels,
            datasets: $.map(datapoints, function (e, i) {
                return {
                    backgroundColor: lineChartColors[i],
                    borderColor: lineChartColors[i],
                    fill: false,
                    data: e,
                    label: suppliers[i],
                    lineTension: 0.2,
                }
            })
        },
        options: {
            layout: {
                padding: {
                    left: 20,
                    right: 40,
                    top: 20,
                    bottom: 20
                }
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'left'

            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Month'
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        callback: function (value, index, values) {
                            return addCommas(value);
                        }
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: yAxisString 
                    }
                }]
            },
            plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                    display: false
                }
            },
            tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                    var datasetLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index].toString();
                    var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ': ';
                    var formattedReturnLabel;
                    if (datatype == "money") {
                        formattedReturnLabel = label + '$' + addCommas(datasetLabel);
                    } else {
                        formattedReturnLabel = label + addCommas(datasetLabel);
                    }
                    return formattedReturnLabel;
                }
            }
        }
        }
    });

})
```

And the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="widget widget-double">
    <div class="m-3 border">
        <table style="cursor: pointer !important;" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("SupplierUnitsByMonth", "Reports")'" class="table mb-0"><thead><tr><th class="text-center">@ViewBag.widgetName</th></tr></thead></table>
        <div class="w-100 aspect-ratio-50 p-2">
            <canvas id="chart-units-history" data-legendlabels="[@ViewBag.Months]" data-suppliers= "[@ViewBag.suppliers]" data-datapoints="[@ViewBag.supplierTotals]" data-datatype="units" class="line-graph w-100 aspect-ratio-50"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart.js - Styling Legend - ONE legend entry per line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61359321/chart-js-styling-legend-one-legend-entry-per-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate custom [HTML legend](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#html-legends) using `legendCallback` together with some `CSS`.

```
legendCallback: chart => {
  let html = '<ul>';
  chart.data.datasets.forEach((ds, i) => {
    html += '<li>' +
      '<span style="width: 36px; height: 14px; background-color:' + ds.backgroundColor + '; border:' + ds.borderWidth + 'px solid ' + ds.borderColor + '" onclick="onLegendClicked(event, \'' + i + '\')">&nbsp;</span>' +
      '<span id="legend-label-' + i + '" onclick="onLegendClicked(event, \'' + i + '\')">' +
      ds.label + '</span>' +
      '</li>';
  });
  return html + '</ul>';
},
```

> To make this behave the same as standard Chart.js charts, the function `onLegendClicked` is invoked when a mouse click occurs on a legend label. This function toggles the hidden state of individual datasets and changes label text style between normal and strike-through.

```
function onLegendClicked(e, i) {
  const hidden = !chart.data.datasets[i].hidden;
  chart.data.datasets[i].hidden = hidden;
  const legendLabelSpan = document.getElementById("legend-label-" + i);
  legendLabelSpan.style.textDecoration = hidden ? 'line-through' : '';
  chart.update();
};
```

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
const lineChartColors = ["#000000", "#fd7730", "#ffd35c", "#3fc6f3", "#28a745", "#488cf2", "#4755d3", "#9768c9", "#f2748d", "#f287e7", '#992499', '#6BD69E'];
const legendlabels = ['Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul'];
const datapoints = [
  [205, 275, 359, 329, 262, 302, 290, 323, 279, 238, 307, 245],
  [16, 13, 14, 11, 23, 11, 24, 23, 15, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 53, 0],
  [169, 194, 261, 193, 151, 158, 128, 143, 163, 173, 139, 208],
  [8, 5, 8, 2, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 19, 36, 7, 35, 27, 30, 13, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 47, 30, 54, 59, 48, 41, 38, 65, 24, 44, 37],
  [12, 16, 27, 33, 18, 46, 70, 89, 23, 41, 71, 0]
];
var suppliers = ["Total", "Starkey", "Resound", "Widex", "Rexton", "Unitron", "Phonak", "Signia"];

function onLegendClicked(e, i) {
  const hidden = !chart.data.datasets[i].hidden;
  chart.data.datasets[i].hidden = hidden;
  const legendLabelSpan = document.getElementById("legend-label-" + i);
  legendLabelSpan.style.textDecoration = hidden ? 'line-through' : '';
  chart.update();
};

const chart = new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: legendlabels,
    datasets: datapoints.map((e, i) => ({
      backgroundColor: lineChartColors[i],
      borderColor: lineChartColors[i],
      fill: false,
      data: e,
      label: suppliers[i],
      lineTension: 0.2,
    }))
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    legendCallback: chart => {
      let html = '<ul>';
      chart.data.datasets.forEach((ds, i) => {
        html += '<li>' +
          '<span style="width: 36px; height: 14px; background-color:' + ds.backgroundColor + '; border:' + ds.borderWidth + 'px solid ' + ds.borderColor + '" onclick="onLegendClicked(event, \'' + i + '\')">&nbsp;</span>' +
          '<span id="legend-label-' + i + '" onclick="onLegendClicked(event, \'' + i + '\')">' +
          ds.label + '</span>' +
          '</li>';
      });
      return html + '</ul>';
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Month'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: "Units Sold"
        }
      }]
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
});
document.getElementById("legend").innerHTML = chart.generateLegend();
```

```css
#chart-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#legend li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 10px 5px 0;
}

#legend li span {
  padding-left: 8px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-wrapper">
  <div id="legend"></div>
  <canvas id="myChart" height="75"></canvas>
</div>
```