# chartJS generateLegend()

Tags: charts, chart.js

I'm new in using chart JS, I am trying to customize the legends. I try the example that I found but when I try to make my own it shows this error.
[image]

I want to display the legends in separate  like in this.
[image]

here's my code.

```
var myLegendContainer = document.getElemenById('legend');
var graphTarget = $("#line-chartcanvas");
                    graphTarget.attr('height',80);
                        barGraphQty = new Chart(graphTarget, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: chartdata,
                        options: {
                            legend: {
                            display: false
                            },
                        }
                    });
                    
                    myLegendContainer.innerHTML = barGraphQty.generateLegend();
                    
                });
```

HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Legends</h3>
    
                    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                    </div>
                
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div id="legend"></div>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
[class$="-legend"] {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 0;
}

[class$="-legend"] li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

[class$="-legend"] li.hidden {
 display:block !important;
  text-decoration: line-through !important;
}

[class$="-legend"] li span {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 10
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's almost impossible to tell why exactly this `TypeError` occurs. From the posted image, I deduct however that the use of [`generatelabels`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration) is not the ideal choice to achieve what you need.

What you really need is generating custom [HTML legend](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#html-legends) using `legendCallback` together with some CSS.

Please take a look at the following posts to see how this could be done:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63216656/2358409
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63202664/2358409